# Is there a way to follow an unanswered question that isn't yours?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Gave the site a little search and I gave my account stuff and the page a quick look over. I couldn't find it.

Also, it would be nice to mark a question that's been answered but not closed that may get a new better answer/new information in comments.

Again this is for a question that isn't mine. Would this be helpful for anyone other than me? I like seeing the answers of questions I didn't know how to answer. Bookmarking them all is crazy talk. I am a curious guy.

Sorry if this is already a feature. I am new here. I don't think this is a duplicate question either... But, what do I know.

Comment: the star on the left, you can star questions and they will appear in your "favorites"

Comment: Ah! I see it now. Dang that's hidden.

Answer (score 4):

If you click on the star beneath the vote buttons you can mark a question as a favorite and then check up on it from time to time from your profile where there is an indication when your favorite questions get updated.

Comment: I sorta feel dumb not seeing it until now.